# How to increase Apace access log line length from 255 to 5000

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

Apache web server is running in Debian linux

Logging is defined as

```
LogFormat "%t %h %>s %O %T \"%r\" \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" (%q)" vhost_combined
```

vhost_combined contains %r directive to log query strings which can be long.

All lines in log file are truncated to 255 characters. Full query strings and remaining combined log parameters are not logged.
How to increase log line length to 5000 characters ?

Comment: What is the **log format for vhost_combined** in your configuration ?

Comment: Try to include %q in the log format for vhost_combined which will most likely Solve your Issue

Comment: @Prem I updated question and added log format

Comment: Adding %q causes query string to written two times since %r is also used. How to log method (GET or POST) , path (/virtdir/a/b/c) and full query string only once in log file like %r logs?

Comment: It looks Correct , not sure what is going wrong to get the truncation. You can try this : `LogFormat "%t %h %>s %m %T %U (%q)" my_format` : this has all that you want. You have to update `CustomLog` to use `my_format`. I think this will not get truncated.